# How do I re-prompt a user to type in an answer?

Tags: java

How would I get the prompt to bring it back to the beginning of the sequence, should i go for a while statement instead?

```
 if (al.contains(room)) {
      System.out.println("Entered "+room);
    }
 else {
     System.err.println("I couldnt get that, please type exactly which room you want to enter:  ");
 }
```

Comment: Yes. Use a while-loop. Simply use `break;` when `al.contains(room)`.

Comment: Perhaps a `do-while` loop; if you want to enter the block at least once.